# How do you utilize a .NET full framework (WCF) process in a .NET 5 service/platform?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, architecture, .net-5

We have a net48 WCF client that wraps the API for this very hard to consume service (made in Java I believe, SOAP and WSDL) and that works great.

Problem is, we're in the process of porting our platform to net5 and I can't port this WCF code since WCF was largely left behind and CoreWCF is moving at a snails pace.

From an architecture standpoint, how do we integrate this into something that can be utilized? Previously we had a Windows Service that would fire off client processes to do the actual communicating. In the new architecture, we'd like to move to something like Hangfire.

Answer (score -1):

Although you can call WCF services in .net core, it is subject to some restrictions. The WCF client in .net core only supports four bindings: BasicHttpBinding, CustomBinding, NetHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding, and there are not many security features in .net Core. My suggestion is to use WCF in the .net framework.

About core's support for WCF, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf).

If you want to use WCF, I suggest you use .net framework instead of .net core. The alternative to WCF in .net core is [gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: That's the problem. The new system I'm building is net core and thus I can't run this process directly, so I need to find a way to do that calling the process that is WCF+Net48

Comment: The compatibility of WCF in core is not good, so I do not recommend using WCF services in core.